# How can I do CRUD operations through CrudRepository in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, jpa, repository, crud

I'm working with PostgresSQL and I have the following interface:

```
@Repository
public interface ExampleRepository extends CrudRepository<ExampleEntity, Long> { }
```

Then I try to get the bean:

```
ExampleRepository repository = ctx.getBean(ExampleRepository.class);
```

Of course, I can't do that, because there's no implementation and eventually I get

```
NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'ExampleRepository'
```

I know this is a wrong approach, but since I'm not enough experienced, I've got no idea how I can communicate with my database. Any example I searched only explained how to implement services & controllers in order to interact with db through Browser. But I want to do CRUD operation inside the java code.

Could anyone explain it to me? Any related sources would also be fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure how you are getting context (ctx) here.
But the common approach is @Repository is not needed instead, @EnableJPARepositories should be used in the @Configuration file. Then use @Autowired to inject the repository into your service class (where you want to execute operation from your repository bean)
You can refer below link for more details
https://mkyong.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-spring-data-jpa/

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to create bean. It will created by the spring framework because you annotated your interface as `@Repository` .You need only `@Autowired` in your service class or where do you want to use this reference.

```
@Autowired 
private ExampleRepository exampleRepository;
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it made zero effect